# Finitely generated subgroups of direct limits of groups

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Let $G$ be a direct limit of groups $G_n$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ (or perhaps even for $n$ in some other directed set, but in my case I only need $\mathbb{N}$).

Is it true that every finitely generated subgroup of $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of some $G_n$?

[EDIT:  I'm adding the category-theory tag in case it helps.  I think category-theorists don't like the term 'direct limit' these days, so please read 'colimit' instead.)

Comment: I think this might be easy, but I'm really tired today and I really want to know the answer, but couldn't find it on the internet or find a suitable book in the library.

Comment: I don't have a counterexample, but you might need finitely presented, not just finitely generated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $(G_n)_{n \in N}$ be a directed system of groups and $(i_n : G_n \to G)_n$ their colimit. Let $H \leq G$ be a finitely *presented* subgroup. Then it is well-known that $H$ is [finitely presentable](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact+object), i.e. $\hom(H,-)$ preserves directed colimits (see Corollary 3.13 in [LPAC](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Locally+Presentable+and+Accessible+Categories)). In particular $H \hookrightarrow G$ factors as $H \xrightarrow{j} G_n \xrightarrow{i_n} G$ for some $n$. We must have that $j$ is a monomorphism. Hence, $H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G_n$.

For the sake of completeness and because it is so easy, here is a direct proof of this factorization: Say that $H$ is generated by $h_1,\dotsc,h_n \in H$, and that the only necessary defining relations are $R_1(h_1,\dotsc,h_n)=\dotsc=R_m(h_1,\dotsc,h_n)=1$, where $R_i$ are words on $n$ letters. Each $h_i$ lies in the image of some $G_m$. Since the system is directed, we can choose some large $m$ which works for all $h_i$. Say $h_i=i_m(g_i)$. Now make $n$ even larger: Each relation already holds in some $G_n$. Since there are only finitely many, they already hold in $G_n$ for some $n \geq m$. But this means precisely that $h_i \mapsto g_i$ extends to a well-defined homomorphism $H \to G_n$.

As you can see, it is crucial here that $G$ is finitely presented. If $G$ is only finitely generated, but not finitely presented, we can write $G$ as the directed colimit of finitely presented groups $G_n$ (by looking at the finite parts of a presentation of $G$), and we can take $H=G$ as a counterexample. There is no reason why $G$ should be isomorphic to a subgroup of $G_n$. In fact, when $G$ has no recursively enumerable set of relations, then Higman has shown (*Subgroups of finitely presented groups*, Proceedings of the Royal Society of London. Series A, Mathematical and Physical Sciences, 1961) that $G$ does not embed into any finitely presented group.

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry it took me so long to get around to accepting this.  I was rather busy.

Answer (score 3):

As Jim points out, the following argument is not quite complete. I'll leave it for now as a partial answer:

Let $g_1,\ldots,g_k$ be the finite generators of your finitely generated subgroup of $G$, then for every $i$, there is some $n_i$ such that $g_i\in G_n$ for every $n\geq n_i$. Define $n^\prime = \max_{i=1,\ldots,k} n_i$, then $g_i\in G_{n^\prime}$ for every $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and thus there is a homomorphism from a subgroup of $G_{n^\prime}$ to the subgroup of $G_n$.

The problem Jim points out seems to be the following:

Let $\langle G|R\rangle$ be a finitely generated group with countably many relations $R = \{r_i|i\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Consider the directed system of groups given by the natural homomorphisms $$\langle G|\{r_i|i\leq k\}\rangle\to\langle G|\{r_i|i\leq k+1\}\rangle$$
The direct limit of this system is $\langle G|R\rangle$, which is finitely generated but is not naturally a subgroup of any $\langle G|\{r_i|i\leq k\}\rangle$.

Comment: Yes.  Thanks.  I hadn't even finished reading the definition of direct limit properly before I asked the question, to be honest!  (I had been thinking about inverse limits yesterday, where I don't think the analogous result is true, and I hadn't quite realised direct limits are so much 'easier').

Comment: I'm tired enough that I'm not going to accept your answer yet even though I'm thoroughly convinced, just in case someone comes along and points out something wrong with it.  I will in a few hours, though (i.e. next time I'm on the site).

Comment: The $G_{n'}$ that you have chosen may contain all the generators of $G$, but it needn't contain all the relations between those generators.  For example $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/2 \to \mathbb Z/2 \to \cdots$ is a direct system with limit $\mathbb Z/2$.  What, in your argument, stops me from taking $1 \in \mathbb Z$ as the preimage of the generator of $\mathbb Z/2$?  Certainly $\mathbb Z/2$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Julien: Yes I changed my answer accordingly. It was too easy to be true :). Can you think of a concrete counterexample though? That would be great!

Comment: @Abel For some reason, the only direct limits I have really worked with had injective connections. So I have an awful intuition of the general case...

Comment: @Jim: Thanks for pointing that out. That's exactly what I was worried about, actually, but then Abel still somehow managed to convince me.

Comment: Sorry for being so convincing :)

Comment: @Abel:  Actually it's much more my fault for not getting enough sleep last night.

Comment: Are you guaranteed to get an isomorphic subgroup here? It seems like you would get that it is a *quotient* of a subgroup of some $G_n$.

Comment: @SteveD Exactly, that's why the proof is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's helpful to introduce some notation first: Let $(N,\le)$ be a directed set (i.e. for all $n,m\in N$ there is $k\in N$ with $k\ge n$ and $k\ge m$). Futher let $f_{nm}: G_n \to G_m\;(n\le m)$ be a directed system of groups. Then the colimit $G=\lim_n G_n$ exists and there are associated group homomorphisms $f_n:G_n \to G$ such that $f_m \circ f_{nm}=f_n\;(n\le m)$.

The colimit in the category of groups (and some other familiar categories like the category of modules over a ring) has the property that for each $g\in G$ there are $n\in N, g_n \in G_n$ with $g=f_n(g_n)$.

Now let $H\le G$ be finitely generated with generators $h_1,...,h_p$. There are $n_i \in N, g_{n_i}\in G_{n_i}$ with $f_{n_i}(g_{n_i})=h_i$. Choose $n\ge n_i\;(i=1,...,p)$. Hence $h_i=f_n(f_{{n_i},n}(g_{n_i}))\in f_n(G_n)$ and therefore

> $$H \le f_n(G_n)$$

If all $f_{nm}$ are injective, $f_n$ is injective as well and $H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G_n$ in this case.

Comment: Yes. The problem is when the connecting maps are not injective.

Comment: This shows that finitely generated groups are finitely generated objects of the category of groups (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/finitely+generated+object).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Could you unfold that statement for me?  I'm not sure why it's relevant sense we are not assuming control over the choice of directed system.

Comment: Have you looked at the nlab article? Please do that first.